# Opening word template and saving as .doc to current workbook folder - VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA in Excel, I am opening a word template file.

I am struggling to save the file as a .doc in the same folder as the active excel workbook. I do not want to save it in the same folder as it was retrieved from, and also do not want to enter another absolute path name.

My current code keeps saving the .doc to C:\Users\USER\Documents instead of the workbooks actual folder (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\testdocs)

My code is as follows:

```
Sub OpenTemplateSaveAsDoc()
Dim wApp As word.Application
Dim wDoc As word.Document
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\USER\Documents\Custom Office Templates\wordtesttemplate.dotm", ReadOnly:=True)

With wDoc

wDoc.SaveAs CurDir & Application.PathSeparator & "MySavedDoc.doc"

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
wDoc.SaveAs CurDir & Application.PathSeparator & "MySavedDoc.doc"
```

to

```
wDoc.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "MySavedDoc.doc"
```

(And, because that bit of code is wrapped with a `With wDoc` block, you can just use `.SaveAs ...` instead of `wDoc.SaveAs ...` - the only purpose of a `With` block is to allow you to avoid typing the `With` object's name within the block.)